# How can I change order of custom menu in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) items for Google Sheets.
On the picture from manual, "Custom Menu" is moved to the left of "Help" built in menu.
Whereas by default the custom menu is placed to the end (to the right).
I didn't find related methods in [Menu class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu.html#addSeparator()) per se.

The reason is to call my scripts by keyboard shortcuts, moving through menu items.
So far the only customized shortcuts are available via useless inconvenient [macro](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros).

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. But I'd love to find out about the flexibility in this if there is any.

Comment: I believe we can eventually - google itself made this screenshot from somewhere :) there should be some custom tag in manifest json file of gs or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, this is not possible in Google Sheet, yet.

if a macro is inconvenient you can perhaps use some 3rd party tools like AutoHotKey.com